# Wubi Install partition and Windows MBR

Tags: installation, partitioning, mbr

I am little afraid of messing up my Windows 7 dual boot mbr (I have 2 Windows 7 installed), which allow booting into either on bootup.

My first question, is whether the Ubuntu loader, is included with the 2 Windows 7 selections on the MBR, or if it the Ubuntu loader is available through some other means, with a ubuntu & windows selection, and then the windows selection taking you to the dual boot Windows 7 selections?

My second question, is selecting the actual location to install ubuntu. All of the write ups advise you select the drive (but didn't mention being able to select a partition on a drive). I would like to install it to one of my partitions on my 2nd drive, where however if only a drive is available, then I assume it will install it into Windows/Programs?

My last question, is that when uninstalled, I assume it removes the Ubuntu loader selection from whereever it is loaded from, per my first question above?

Answer (score 1):

When you install Wubi, the default installation location is C:/ubuntu.  You can change the partition to install wubi, but the location will **always** be DRIVE:/ubuntu  .

I'm not sure what you mean by the first question, but after you install wubi, it adds a Ubuntu entry (which leads to GRUB) in the Windows Boot Menu **without** rewriting the MBR.  When you remove wubi, the uninstaller will remove the ubuntu entry.

If you really messed up the MBR, I recommend downloading [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) which allows you to modify the Windows Boot Menu.